# How to reshape a numpy array from (#dim1,#dim2,#channel) to (#channel, #dim1,#dim2)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, reshape

I have an array with the shape of `(#dim1,#dim2,#channel)`. I want to reshape it to `(#channel, #dim1,#dim2)`.

The `plt.reshape(x,  (#channel, #dim1,#dim2))` shows me a wrong image.

Comment: How do you know the image is wrong?

Comment: By matching their attributes. Also ``plt.imshow()`` gives the error of ``Wrong dimension``

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data? Generally reshaping using numpy works quite well.

Comment: Downloaded Cifar10 by following the below code:
[link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the Cifar10 dataset you could use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cPickle

def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = cPickle.load(fo)
    return dict

# Read the data
imageDict = unpickle('cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_2')
imageArray = imageDict['data']

# Now we reshape
imageArray = np.swapaxes(imageArray.reshape(10000,32,32,3,order='F'), 1, 2)

# Get the labels
labels = ['airplane','automobile','bird','cat','deer','dog','frog','horse','ship','truck']
imageLabels = [labels[i] for i in imageDict['labels']]

# Plot some images
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,4, figsize=(8,8))
for axIndex in [(i,j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]:
    index = np.random.randint(0,10000)
    ax[axIndex].imshow(imageArray[index], origin='upper')
    ax[axIndex].set_title(imageLabels[index])
    ax[axIndex].axis('off')
fig.show()
```

Which gives you:
[image]